# OOP PHP Can't get new mysqli from other class

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I have class, where i make connection to database and do some queries.

But i can't make query to this database from other class. Problem is that class `Cd` can't see db connection command -> can't make a query. Here is the code:

```
require_once('config.php');
class myClass
{
    public $mysqli;
    public $res;
    function connect()
    {
        $database = new Database();

        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($database->db_host, $database->db_user, $database->db_pass, $database->db_table);
    }
    function cd($id)
    {
       ......
        }
    }        
}

class Cd extends myClass
{
    function cdname($id)
    {
        $get= new Scandiweb();
        $get->mysqli;

        $this->res = $get->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM disk WHERE id=" . $id . "");
        if ($this->res->num_rows > 0) {
            .........
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: share the code of `config.php` file?

Comment: Are we allowed to tag this question as `oop`?

Comment: why did you extends Scandiweb??? your db class name is myClass...so you need to create object of myClass insted scandiweb...

Comment: Frankly, all this stuff makes very little sense and hardly can be called OOP. Better leave this idea for a while and write procedural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit messy, so it's hard to tell where exactly the problem lies:

- Why do you require config?
- Why do you create a Database (which is more like a DbConfig) in the constructor instead of passing it?
- What is the Scandiweb-class?
- Why do you call mysqli->query on that class instead of `$this`

The last one is your immediate mistake. You extend `myClass` which creates the mysqli-connection and stores it as class variable `$this->mysqli`. That means that the child class `Cd` will have access to it. When you extend a class you can call all it's public and protected properties and methods. Only those marked as private can't be accessed.

That means instead of accessing `$get->mysqli->query(...)` you can do `$this->mysqli->query(...)`. What would make sense in OOP is to create a connection once (like you do in the constructor) and pass it around to the services requiring a database connection. This is called Dependency Inversion Principle and using a Dependency Container makes it easier (but is not mandatory).

There are so called design patterns that will make it easier to deal with performing sql queries like in your code above. The most common ones are the [Active Record-pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) as used in Laravel's Eloquent and the Propel library, the [Table Data Gateway-pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) as used in Zend Framework's DB-component and the [Data Mapper-pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) as employed by Doctrine ORM. If you want to write OOP code you should look at their documentation and maybe use one of those instead of dealing with everything yourself.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I just made some mistakes in code that i've gave you. In original code i don't have any.